# ST_DWithin matches wrong points

Tags: postgis, area

The following query crosses every city called "London" with every "place" (**both** of which are in London, UK) and calculates the distance. The points are of type geography.

```
SELECT
  c."Name",
  ST_Distance(c."Point", p."Point") AS distance,
FROM tbl_city c
CROSS JOIN tbl_place p
WHERE c."Name" = 'London'
ORDER BY distance
```

Here are the first eleven rows...

```
"United Kingdom (no new registrations, see also UK)";2944.41260216;"POINT(-0.093689 51.514125)"
"United Kingdom (no new registrations, see also UK)";117860.75442904;"POINT(-0.093689 51.514125)"
"Russian Federation";5104882.83141283;"POINT(79.55 52.8)"
"Nigeria";5107678.2307221;"POINT(5.787874 5.722571)"
"Russian Federation";5163562.27158004;"POINT(79.55 52.8)"
"Nigeria";5223264.09191264;"POINT(5.787874 5.722571)"
"Equatorial Guinea";5536969.64612286;"POINT(9.8 2.2833333)"
"Equatorial Guinea";5651405.27352597;"POINT(9.8 2.2833333)"
"Canada";5837198.7351878;"POINT(-81.25 42.983333)"
"Canada";5892304.825859;"POINT(-81.25 42.983333)"
"United States";5902600.98457156;"POINT(-80.1488889 41.1436111)"
```

However, this query returns nothing. In fact, I don't appear to get a result back until I raise the distance to 100,000, and then it returns London Colney, which is outside of London, UK.

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT
        c."CityId",
        c."Name", 
        (SELECT Count(*)
        FROM tbl_place p
        WHERE ST_DWithin(p."Point", c."Point", 3000, false)) AS "PlaceCount"
    FROM tbl_city c) a
WHERE "Name" LIKE 'Lond%' AND "PlaceCount" > 2
ORDER BY "PlaceCount" DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

Where am I going wrong?

The following query returns three rows (one for every place). The city is London, UK. If I change the range down to 117000, it only returns one result. So somehow, the other two places are only within 118km of London but not within 117km, which is of course nonsense, because all three places are very close.

```
SELECT
c."CityId",
c."Name",
p."Name" AS "Place"
FROM tbl_city c
INNER JOIN tbl_place p
ON ST_DWithin(p."Point", c."Point", 118000)
WHERE c."Name" = 'London'
```

Cross over is at 117861m. lol.

Comment: For the first query what is the second and third distances?  I would remove the `AND "PlaceCount" > 2` and determine how many places are within 3000 first.  I am going to say the count for `London, UK` will be 1 (maybe 2) given that you have only added 56 to the distance of the closest place.

Comment: @MickyT I've updated the question. Its should have been ">1" because there are only two places. When I remove that condition and the limit, I get 234 rows, including Londoni in Fuji!? POINT(178.55 -17.7333333)

Comment: I imported the data from here... https://www.maxmind.com/en/free-world-cities-database

Comment: How many rows in the place table and what do they represent.  Maybe also what you are trying to achieve.  I may be able to help, but I need to know the final goal and have a general idea of the data you are working with,  Currently I can only see that you have maybe to place points at around 3km and 118km from London.

Comment: Two place rows. They're just locations and there will be many. The idea is to type in a city, the database looks for matches but only returns those which have places close by. So 'Lond%' will be a parameter and "PlaceCount" > 2 will be "> 0". The places are never explicitly linked to the cities.

Comment: Apart from what others have said, I think the reason you get so many rows when you remove the Placecount>2 is because your geometry data are in lat/lon, so, 3000 will cover the whole world, meaning all places that start Lond will pass the test. If you cast you geometries to geography, then the calc will happen in meters instead.

Comment: But the docs that it's in meters when the points are type geography.

Comment: Exactly. Sorry, it wasn't clear from your question whether your types are geometry or geography, but the behavior you reported is consistent with them being geometries.

Comment: I wrote that they're geographies in the question.

Comment: Sorry, missed that, right at the start too. Where does tbl_place come from. I imported the cities from maxmind link, but can't test any further without tbl_place, or at least, an example row or two.

Comment: They're created manually. But, if you see my answer, I found the problem. It was my misleading data.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that your current query is not returning anything is because you do not have the data there to complete the query that you want.
I think that you are heading in the right direction, but you will need to have more data in your places table to properly realise the way the query will behave.

You stated in your comments that you want to you want to search cities, but only return those that have places nearby.  The query that you have put up should do the trick, but you may want to try a couple of different variations.

Here's one variation that may work for you.  It makes sure that only cities which have a place within 3000 will be returned by doing a spatial join.

```
SELECT c."CityId", c."Name", count(*) number_of_places
FROM tbl_city c
    INNER JOIN tbl_place p ON ST_DWithin(p."Point", c."Point", 3000)
WHERE c."Name" like 'Lond%'
GROUP BY c.cityid, c.name
```

If you want to make sure there are multiple places within distance then you could add a having clause to the query, eg `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`

Comment: A group by appears to result in the same oddness of the place count being only 1 instead of 2, even when the places are virtually the same. I've added a third place - same again. Looks like a bug.

Comment: No, its not a bug, my data was poor. :)

Answer (score 0):

This was merely a stupid mistake. My app's code wasn't updating the place's point column being used in the query and the data in the point query wasn't actually near London. So I thought I was setting the points close to London, but it wasn't really doing it!